# Helm bind "C-j" and "C-k" to list navigation (cursor position)

Tags: key-bindings, helm, evil

Is it possible to change binding to navigate throw Helm list via `C-j` and `C-k` bindings? I came to Emacs from Vi(m) world and I really want to keep this mapping in my emacs + evil setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> if you want, and have the escape key on e.g. <kbd>C-k</kbd>.  See this [hydra wiki entry](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki/Helm).

The code:

```cl
(defhydra helm-like-unite (:hint nil
                           :color pink)
  "
Nav ^^^^^^^^^        Mark ^^          Other ^^       Quit
^^^^^^^^^^------------^^----------------^^----------------------
_K_ ^ ^ _k_ ^ ^     _m_ark           _v_iew         _i_: cancel
^↕^ _h_ ^✜^ _l_     _t_oggle mark    _H_elp         _o_: quit
_J_ ^ ^ _j_ ^ ^     _U_nmark all     _d_elete
^^^^^^^^^^                           _f_ollow: %(helm-attr 'follow)
"
  ;; arrows
  ("h" helm-beginning-of-buffer)
  ("j" helm-next-line)
  ("k" helm-previous-line)
  ("l" helm-end-of-buffer)
  ;; beginning/end
  ("g" helm-beginning-of-buffer)
  ("G" helm-end-of-buffer)
  ;; scroll
  ("K" helm-scroll-other-window-down)
  ("J" helm-scroll-other-window)
  ;; mark
  ("m" helm-toggle-visible-mark)
  ("t" helm-toggle-all-marks)
  ("U" helm-unmark-all)
  ;; exit
  ("<escape>" keyboard-escape-quit "" :exit t)
  ("o" keyboard-escape-quit :exit t)
  ("i" nil)
  ;; sources
  ("}" helm-next-source)
  ("{" helm-previous-source)
  ;; rest
  ("H" helm-help)
  ("v" helm-execute-persistent-action)
  ("d" helm-persistent-delete-marked)
  ("f" helm-follow-mode))
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<escape>") 'helm-like-unite/body)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-k") 'helm-like-unite/body)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-o") 'helm-like-unite/body)
```

How the hint looks:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

This is what I actually need:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-j") 'helm-next-line)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-k") 'helm-previous-line)
```

Thanks @abo-abo for help!